# Laravel custom artisan command cannot access model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to create a artisan command to dump data from database table in my existing Laravel 6 project.

I'm following the web to create the command, it works and prints out.
https://codeinphp.github.io/post/creating-your-own-artisan-in-php/

However I could not access the model in the existing project.

I've tried using

```
MyModel::all()
```

but it returns error about connection

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   connection() on null

I also tried do the data dump using existing getCsv() from controller, like

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\MyController')->getCsv();
```

Then it complains

> Class request does not exist

I also tired doing

```
$table = DB::table('my_table');
```

But error returns as

> A facade root has not been set

Comment: Why so complicated, when you can simply use laravel commands? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/artisan#writing-commands

Comment: A CLI command doesn't have a `request`, only web pages running through your webserver do. As for your model problem, we'd need to see the code of your command to know what went wrong

Comment: Thanks @JulianS it works.